# How can I use vb to get pdf context?

Tags: vb6, acrobat

I have a function that can get the page's number of the pdf file.

```
Public Function GetNumPages(ByVal PdfFile As String) As Long  
    Dim objTempDoc As Object  
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject  
    Set fso = New FileSystemObject  

    If fso.FileExists(PdfFile ) Then  
        Set objTemp = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")  
        objTemp.Open pstrPdfFilename  
        GetNumPages = objTemp.GetNumPages  
        objTemp.Close  
        Set objTemp = Nothing  
    End If  

    Set fso = Nothing  
End Function
```

I want to get the last line's context in last page of pdf file.

I have found this API, but I don't know how to use it.
Will it return the context that I want?

> PDOCContext PDDocGetOCContext(PDDoc pdDoc)

I tried this way to use API, but it was fail.

```
Set objTempDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
objTempDoc.Open PdfFile
myPDFPage = objTempDoc.GetOCContext
```

Comment: PDOCContext isn't an object in the Acrobat Interapplication Communication API. If you are trying to get a PDPage object, use AquirePage(nPage) with your PDDoc object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can call this Function to get the text of last page.

```
Public Function GetPDFText(ByVal pstrPdfFilename As String) As String

        Dim PDDoc As Object
        Dim CAcroRect As New Acrobat.AcroRect
        Dim PDPage As Acrobat.AcroPDPage
        Dim PDTxtSelect As Acrobat.AcroPDTextSelect
        Dim CArcoPoint As Acrobat.AcroPoint
        Dim iNumWords As Integer
        Dim iMax As Long
        Dim arPdfLines() As String
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim fso As FileSystemObject

        Set fso = New FileSystemObject
        If fso.FileExists(pstrPdfFilename) Then
            Set PDDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
            PDDoc.Open pstrPdfFilename
            Set PDPage = PDDoc.AcquirePage(PDDoc.GetNumPages() - 1)
            Set CArcoPoint = PDPage.GetSize()
            CAcroRect.Top = CArcoPoint.y
            CAcroRect.Left = 0
            CAcroRect.Right = CArcoPoint.x
            CAcroRect.bottom = 0
            Set PDTxtSelect = PDDoc.CreateTextSelect(PDDoc.GetNumPages() - 1, CAcroRect)
            If PDTxtSelect Is Nothing Then
                iNumWords = 0
                iMax = 0
                GetPDFLastLineText = ""
            Else
                iNumWords = PDTxtSelect.GetNumText
                iMax = iNumWords - 1
                Dim ii As Long
                For ii = 0 To iMax
                GetPDFLastLineText = GetPDFLastLineText & PDTxtSelect.GetText(ii)
            Next
        End If
        PDDoc.Close
    End If

    Set fso = Nothing
    Set PDDoc = Nothing
    Set CAcroRect = Nothing
    Set PDPage = Nothing
    Set PDTxtSelect = Nothing
    Set CArcoPoint = Nothing

End Function
```